Multipart Form data is getting stored as txt instead of pdf
I am stuck here since a long time.
I wanted to upload the document I got from drive into invoice ninja.
The file is getting uploaded but its type is txt and is not readable.
public static void uploadFile(List<String> fileIds,String invoiceId)
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> filesData = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (String fileId : fileIds) {
            Map<String, Object> fileData = getFileFromGoogleDrive(fileId);
            if (fileData != null) {
                filesData.add(fileData);
            }
        }
        if (filesData.isEmpty()) {
            System.debug('No files to upload');
            return;
        }

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://invoicing.co/api/v1/invoices/' + invoiceId + '/upload');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('x-api-token', INVOICE_NINJA_API_TOKEN);
        req.setHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        Map<String, Object> fileData = filesData[0];
        Blob fileBlob = (Blob) fileData.get('blob');
        String fileName = (String) fileData.get('name');
        String mimeType = (String) fileData.get('mimeType');
        System.debug('mimeType-'+mimeType);
        // Multipart form-data
        String boundary = '---------------------------' + DateTime.now().getTime();
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
        String bodyBlob = '--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"\r\n\r\nPUT\r\n';
        String header = '--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="documents[0]"; filename="' + fileName + '"\r\nContent-Type:'+mimeType+'\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n\r\n';
        String footer = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--\r\n';
        System.debug('fileBlob');
        System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob));
        String body = bodyBlob + header + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob) + footer;

        req.setBody(body);

        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200 || res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
            System.debug('Files uploaded successfully: ' + res.getBody());
    }
}

